# Using WebJars with Maven - on Intellij and/or Eclipse

Tags: javascript, eclipse, maven, intellij-idea, webjars

I really tried hard but I cannot figure out how to let Maven handle WebJars so that I can:

- use the JavaScript libraries while programming
- include the required files when packaging and deploying

Adding the dependencies to the `pom.xml` lets Maven download the files - so far so good. But Maven does not copy the content to the build directory so that the resulting path and file structure contains the dependencies.

My project can be found here: https://github.com/anthraxn8b/m3

I am new to nearly everything I use.

Answer (score 4):

The JARs are copied to the WEB-INF/lib folder, when you package the WAR file. That's sufficient, you then can just access the resources (for example AngularJS with the path /webjars/angularjs/2.0.0-alpha.22/angular2.js).

Comment: THX! That's what happens when I build the war. Okay. But how do I get it running with an integrated server (tomcat for example)? The exploded war created and used as an artifact in IntelliJ does not contain the files...

Comment: As long as the JARs are on the classpath, when you run the application, it's fine.

Comment: I just imported your project in IntelliJ, and the JARs are included when i build the exploded war. So there is something wrong in your project configuration, if that doesn't happen in your environment.

Answer (score 0):

Also you need to configure resources in your spring mvc xml/java annotation config.

I do not remember equivalent but in java annotation config it is as follows:

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    if (!registry.hasMappingForPattern("/resources/webjars/**")) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/webjars/**").addResourceLocations("/webjars/");
    }
}
```